# Get difference time with format 'Y-m-d H:i:s' in php?

Tags: php

Example i have

```
$time1 = "2013-11-21 12:59:00";
$time2 = "2013-11-21 13:01:00";
```

How to get the difference of two time above to this format "Y-m-d H:i:s"??

Comment: It's already in format

Comment: @sectus what do you mean? i have tried to decrease the time2 with time1 but the result is not right

Comment: If I had a nickel for everytime this question has been asked...

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha, sorry for the silly question

Comment: ;-) Look over to the right under **Related** >>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time1 = new DateTime('2013-11-21 12:59:00');
$time2 = new DateTime('2013-11-21 13:01:00');
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);

echo $interval->y . " Year " .$interval->m . " Month " .$interval->d ." Days ". $interval->h . " Hours, " . $interval->i." Mintues, ".$interval->s." seconds <br/>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
  $date1 = new DateTime("2013-11-21 12:59:00");
    $date2 = new DateTime("2013-11-21 13:01:00");
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2); 
echo "DIFF: ".$interval->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time1 = strtotime("2013-11-21 12:59:00");
$time2 = strtotime("2013-11-21 12:59:00");
$diff = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time2-$time1);
echo $diff;
```